# Html.BeginForm does not return correct instance of Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make Html.BeginForm to return the current Instance of Model instead of a new instance.

To explain what is wrong, when i write somthing in the TextBoxFor() and click on the submit button in the html.beginform(), it correctly does the AddStatus() and places it in the statusDict with the right key and is displayed on the right side in the view in the foreach loop. When i then click on the "fortsæt" button on the right side, it corrects loads the value into the TextBoxFor since i have it default to Model.MailTitel. Now i want to change what is in the Model.Mailtitel and when i click submit i want it to return this specific instance of the model to the controller but with a new value for MailTitel and since this would be a instance of the model already in the statusDict, it should just update the @status.Value.MailTitel. However since Html.BeginForm() returns a new instance of the model and thus is not in the statusDict which leads to it being added to it and thus shows as a new card on the right side.

So my question is: How to make Html.BeginForm() return the same instance of Model as the controller gave to the view?

Code:

View:

```
@using DS_Prototype.Models
<!--Left side - Info filling -->
<div class="split left">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() // helps mitigate against cross-site request forgery
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.MailTitel, new { @Value = Model.MailTitel })
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-login">Submit</button>
    }
</div>

<!--Right side - Status overview -->
<div class="split right">
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DriftStatus> status in (Dictionary<string, DriftStatus>)Session["statusDict"])
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                @status.Value.MailTitel
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Fortsæt", "ContinueStatus", "Home", new { status_id = status.Key }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Afslut", "EndStatus", "Home", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Submit(DriftStatus driftstatus) {
            AddStatus(driftstatus);
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View("Index", new DriftStatus());
        }

        public ActionResult ContinueStatus(string status_id)
        {
            return View("Index",FindStatus(status_id));
        }

        private DriftStatus FindStatus(string key)
        {
            Dictionary<string, DriftStatus> statusDict = Check_statusDict();
            DriftStatus driftstatus = statusDict[key];
            if (driftstatus == null)
            {
                return new DriftStatus();
            }
            return statusDict[key];
        }

        private void AddStatus(DriftStatus driftstatus)
        {
            Dictionary<string, DriftStatus> statusDict = Check_statusDict();
            if (!statusDict.ContainsKey(driftstatus.Created))
            {
                driftstatus.Created = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                statusDict.Add(driftstatus.Created, driftstatus);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the right-side view razor code is outside the `@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` as it appears, then the data isn't part of the form.

Comment: Are you using "entities.SaveChanges()"?

Comment: You can't return the same instance, it always create a new one since the web is stateless. You'll need to save it to the database, a session or put all the needed fields inside your form.

Comment: In the `index.cshtml` you should add `@model MailTitel` to specify the model of the view. if your model has `Id` you should use `hidden inputs` to save the passed model data.